# symfony2 don't validate file upload on update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I want to update the single entity field using ajax. Basically I don't have form, Simply I am triggering ajax by clicking link passing id and value. But I have mutiple file fields in entity form. So while I update the entity **PrePersist** and **PostPersist** functions are triggering for file upload. I don't want to do this on this update.

My Controller Action

```
public function ajaxupdateAction(Request $request){

        $data  =  $request->query->get('data');

        $id = $data['id'];

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $entry = $em->getRepository('RootContestBundle:Entry')->find($id);

        if (!$entry) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Entry entity.');
        }

        $form =  $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id,'is_liked'=>true))
                    ->add('id', 'hidden')
                    ->add('is_liked','hidden')
                    ->getForm();      
        $entry->setIsLiked(true);
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        $em->persist($entry);

        $em->flush();

     return new JsonResponse(array('reverse'=>'dislike'));

    }
```

What I am doing wrong, How can I solve this !

Comment: Give me your postPersist subscriber. When I do the file upload i add the event subscriber to a Form(ex `postBind`) but not to entity

Comment: @MaxMałecki: I did exactly as in [symfony2 cook book](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html). So How can add event subscriber to form instant of entity

Answer (score 0):

Here you got an documentation about the form event subscribers:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

1. Use the `postBind` event.
2. Then check if the form `isValid()`
3. If it is valid call your service responsible for file upload.

Here is how I did this:

```
public function postBind(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();

    $form = $event->getForm();
    $file = $form->get('upload')->getData();
    if($file && $form->isValid())
    {
        $result = $this->upload->uploadFile($file);
        $data->setUpload($result);
    }
    $event->setData($data);
}
```

My method has the upload service injected by DI and assigned to variable `$this->upload`.